# error C2065: 'ID_MUTATE_GROUP' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm rather new to C++ so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I am creating a text editor in MFC.

Firstly I created a new menu item using VC2010's Resource Editor.

This compiled and ran fine.

I then changed all references to the class CView in the View.cpp file to CRichEditView and included afxrich.h in the View.h file.

Upon compiling I get the following error..............

```
error C2065: 'ID_MUTATE_GROUP' : undeclared identifier
```

As the program was able to compile and run before I changed all references to the class CView in the View.cpp file to CRichEditView and included afxrich.h in the View.h file, I assume that this is what is causing the problem.

Any idea how to fix this?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

P.S: I didn't include any code because, all the code so far has been automatically generated by VS2010, so most everything should be working fine....but if you need to see code i will add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resource.h is not included into your source file.